# Gelman in Qura'n. Is gay encouraged in heaven?

Tags: quran-translation, jannah, ayah

In certain Ayahs of Qur'an, it is mentioned that Allah gifts a wonderful *Gelman* to a good man in heaven. I'm not that familiar with arabic language, but as my best of knowledge *Gelman*, means a (servant/slave) beautiful boy. In that case why should God advertise a Gelman in heaven? Is gay encouraged in heaven?

e.g Take a look at Tur, Ayah 24.

> وَ يَطُوفُ عَلَيْهِمْ غِلْمانٌ لَهُمْ کَأَنَّهُمْ لُؤْلُؤٌ مَکْنُونٌ
>
> There will circulate among them [servant] boys [especially] for them, as if they were pearls well-protected.

Note that "هِمْ" is for male, that means "them" is about male not female. The above translation is taken from [here](http://quran.com/52/24).

Comment: is difference between "getting served" and "having sex" so not-clear? or having good-looking servants implies "having sex with them too" ?!?

Comment: @kmonsoor, before asking a question read carefully. Where is getting serve in above ayeh? They belong to. Where is good looking in above ayeh? Pearls well protected means good looking man in your culture? Are you well protected pearl?

Comment: Your statement *"Note that "هِمْ" is for male, that means "them" is about male not female."* is not correct in Arabic -as in most languages I know of- in plural if there's a mix of gender with at least one male the masculine form would be used. This doesn't by default exclude females. Further Ghelman is the plural of Ghulam which means little (young) boy/man and may also be used to reefer to male servants or slaves .

Comment: @Medi1Saif, Unlike most of the languages, for women there is a very specific term in plural form in Arabic: "هن". When explicitly "هم" is used, it means either all of them are male or there are males among them. But you made a good point, Gelman is a plural of Gholam, but it is not used in that context in this Ayah. Hence, I explained the other side: even if it was not related to Gholam (back then), it is still masculine.

Comment: Again wrong what you've described applies to all languages I know of: there are terms/identifiers for a female plural if all individuals are females ("هن") and there's a term for male and mixed plural ( "هم). It might not appear as a pronoun or whatever in most cases the conjugation is specific, but one can easily distinguish between a (only) female group and a not only female group. The issue in Arabic is rather between the dual plural 2 people (only) and the >2 plural. Here it is sometimes difficult to distinguish.

Comment: For instance, in English we say "them" for both male and female, in Persian, we say "آنها" for both male and female. There could be odd old terms that are not in common use, but these are what we use. Anyways, I do not understand what's your point after all? First, you said Hem is not for males, and for males and females we have the same word in Arabic and I explained to you that you are wrong, and there is a very explicit term used for women in Arabic. Anyways, I believe you just want to resist without having any logic backing you up, so pardon me if I ignore you on this thread.

Answer (score 2):

1.There is nothing in this verse implying that homosexuality will be happening in the Heaven. This verse is talking about the handsome servants serving and respecting the believers in the Heaven.

2.In Surah 43 verse 71 Allah says: “Gold dishes and cups will be passed amongst those in Heaven and they will take pleasure in whatever they desire and whatever they see,”

regarding this verse some commentators on the Quran have raised the following question:

**does the generality of this verse include things that were forbidden in this world as well? If a person in Heaven wants a forbidden item would it be given to him?**

then they have answered the above question in the following way:

> these questions are asked without paying attention to the point that
>   forbidden food, for example, in reality, is food that is unsuitable
>   for man’s spirit and a healthy spirit would not have an appetite for
>   such a food. Sick spirits are those that go after unsuitable food, or
>   even poison, from time to time. There are some sicknesses where one
>   feels the urge to eat dirt, but when cured the false urge disappears.
>   People in Heaven never have desires for such unclean items because
>   their spirit is being taken in the direction of purity and overall
>   goodness.

For further information please visit: http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa847

Comment: So, "they were pearls well-protected" means handsome in your opinion? This is a way of talking about beautiful woman not about a handsome man.

Comment: so you're agreed with me that this verse is talking about the beauty of a group of people and since Gelman is the plural of Golam meaning a male servant, we can make sure that this verse is talking about handsome boys.

Comment: It's not about andsome boy. It's what known in current urban culture or in old poems as boys which are serve others in sex. Sure in current classical culture nobody talk about them as a servant in sex.

Comment: @Saeed There had never been before Islam homosexual relations among Arabs. In fact, when Qur'an forbad homosexuality, people started to ask what does homosexuality means. Golam means young boy, does not refer in any sense to being handsome or homosexual. People used to call their young son Golam : http://www.almaany.com/home.php?language=arabic&lang_name=%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A&word=%D8%BA%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85

Comment: @hawk, Where is your reference for your claim: "There had never been before Islam homosexual relations among Arabs", There are samples of homosexual history even in Qur'an (If you can trust it as a reference). On the other hand, this question didn't ask about what was the history of Arabs (though, Qur'an is not just for Arabs, is it?). This adjective: "they were pearls well-protected" shows how does they look like and this adjective is not for a handsome man, it's for what I said. There are poems from different poets of different cultures who are using a similar adjectives, in similar cases.

Comment: @hawk, 1. I asked for a reference for your other claim, not for the one you had reference. Read my comment very carefully with open eyes. 2. If you want to do false analogy by your latest sentence, I should say that I'm personally direct, but I read books of different cultures, and that word is not used to describe a handsome man in any culture. Someone simply can say handsome man, because of lack of your knowledge don't try to do false analogy, everyone knows how to deal with this shaming strategy better than you.

Comment: @Saeed my apologies. I did not insinuate anything with that sentence. I have homosexual friends from both genders and judging people is definitly not my job. All what I wanted to tell you that Qur'an waa revealed in Mecca Arabic when Mecca Arabs did not know homosexuality. You mentioned poerty and I asked you to post sole poetry before Islam mentions homosexuality from Mecca. After Islam there is a LOT I can tell you. My point is how could you interpret "well-protected pearls" if it had not mentioned in any context before Qur'an?
I am sorry again

Comment: @Saeed and yed there is an example in Qur'an of homosexual peopl (Loot). But those were not in Mecca and Mecca arabs never heard of them. My reference will provide it once I reach home and use my computer.

Comment: @hawk, First of all I asked you for a reference for your claim, second I said if you looking for arabic content (I didn't claim on arabic poetry), I said Qur'an itself has this example. Right now I see you added another comment. Please read my comments carefully before answering them, otherwise is just wasting time to me to repeat what I said. And finally you asked for Mecca (Lot was the prophet of descendants of Ibrahim, and I think muslims claim that Ibrahim was also Muslim as they were). Finally again in my previous comments I wrote that perhaps we should consider Qur'an for all nations ->

Comment: As otherwise if you saying Qur'an was just for Arabs of that period in Mecca, then why someone should think about it? (e.g you said you read it thoughtfully).
P.S: Anyway I will wait for your reference, though as I mentioned in my very early reply to you, even if you have that reference doesn't change anything except that shows you are not talking randomly.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, gay is not encouraged in Heaven. Why? for the following three reasons:

- **First:** Qur'an forbade alcohol in this life:

[image]

> They ask thee concerning wine and gambling. Say: "In them is great sin, and some profit, for men; but the sin is greater than the profit." (Al-Baqara; 2:219)

But that does not apply to Heaven. However, Qur'an clarifies that Heaven's alcohol does not cause the negative symptoms that we see in this life:

[image]

> There will circulate among them young boys made eternal (17) With vessels, pitchers and a cup [of wine] from a flowing spring (18) No headache will they have therefrom, nor will they be intoxicated (19)".

It is clear that alcohol in Heaven is different than what we know such that it does not entail any negative symptoms. Allah forbade alcohol in this life but He has mentioned reasons for that and has mentioned those reasons are void in the hereafter. In the same way, Allah has asked us to avoid homosexuality in this life:

> And [We had sent] Lot when he said to his people, "**Do you commit such
> immorality** as no one has preceded you with from among the
> worlds?(80)**Indeed, you approach men with desire, instead of women.
> Rather, you are a transgressing people."**(81) [Al-Araf 80-81](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u6Oy.png)

[Ash-Shura 25:165-166](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u6Oy.png)

> Do you approach males among the worlds(165).And leave what your Lord
> has created for you as mates? But you are a people
> transgressing."(166)

[Al-Naml27:55](http://www.aleftoday.info/article.php?id=4938)

> Do you indeed approach men with desire instead of women? Rather, you
> are a people behaving ignorantly."

[Quran 4:16](http://www.aleftoday.info/article.php?id=4938)

For all this, if homosexuality is encouraged in Heaven, should not be a single reason to clarify why it is allowed in the same way alcohol is allowed?

- **Second:** The Ayah you mentioned:

> وَ يَطُوفُ عَلَيْهِمْ غِلْمانٌ لَهُمْ کَأَنَّهُمْ لُؤْلُؤٌ مَکْنُونٌ
>
> There will circulate among them [servant] boys [especially] for them, as if they were pearls well-protected.

Qur'an was revealed in Arabic and specifically in Mecca Arabic. The best way to understand words meaning has always been based on Mecca Arabic meanings at that time and/or before Qur'an revelation. In Mecca, there was no homosexuality (although there were a lot of horrible heterosexuality forms). That is, Arabs had used poetry to document all their life aspects. However, in pre-Islamic poetry, we do not see anyone mentions homosexuality in any context. I am sorry to provide Arabic study here [homosexuality in poetry](http://www.aleftoday.info/article.php?id=4938) But English studies are not available for free [Homoeroticism in Classical Arabic Literature](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005ZODQCA). In fact, all who mentioned that there was homosexuality in pre-Islamic has provided poems from Islamic era!
Subsequently, if (well-protected pearls) had not been mentioned in any context before Qur'an, we cannot jump to a conclusion and say it implies homosexuality because in other languages and cultures do, can we?

- **Third:** *Note that "هِمْ" is for male, that means "them" is about male not female*
  **I am afraid that is incorrect either.** It is well known that Arabic language is not genderless like English or Persian. For example, in English *they* for group of males and *they* for group of females. While in Arabic, like some other languages ([e.g. French: ils: male, elles: female](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/ss/subjectpronouns.htm)), two different pronouns are used ([Homa: Male, Hunna: Female](http://arabic.desert-sky.net/g_pronouns.html). Now, the question is, **What if the group is a mix of males and females?** [In French, Ils is used with all-male or mixed groups](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/French/Grammar/Pronouns), In the same way, In Arabic, [a mixed group of males and females will be always referred to by plural masculine pronouns or conjugations](http://arabic.tripod.com/Pronouns1.htm). Hence, "هِمْ" is for male is not necessarily for male
- Last note, in Islam, it is believed that our brains are granted by Allah, the ultimate creator. As a result, these brains will never transcend their creator's power. The human-designed computer, will never go beyond what the human being has designed for, unless there are design errors. A small test for this that challenges our capabilities, ask anybody to use his prolific imagination and tell you about new unprecedented creature he imagines. The best s/he can do is migrate some existed pictures or parts to formulate this creature. He will never be able to create something from nothing known. The profit Muhammed has said "Allah said:

‘I have prepared for My righteous servants what no eye has seen and no ear has heard, nor has it occurred to the human heart.".

My understanding of Heaven description in Qur'an is to motivate people to be good in life and not to think of rewards details and what kind of sexual pleasures they will get.

Comment: As after a long time there is no other better answer, I'll accept this answer which is more thoughtful than the other one. But as the other answer there are lots of claims without proof (and I cannot believe they are right), like this one: "In Mecca, there was no homosexuality", while this doesn't change anything (even if is correct, does not lead to any conclusion), but I just suggest never use any claim without any proof.

Comment: Why do you bring up the issue of alcohol as well as french and arabica grammatical rules while talking about homosexuality ? It looks completely off topic. I find it similar to bringing up malaria and jazz music while talking about fukushima.